# “error: capture of non-variable” within use of lambda in a class

Tags: c++

I have a working c++ class that has a header file and a cpp file where the following lines are in one of the functions of this class in the cpp file:

```
the robot(robot_ip);
   services
        .advertiseService<franka_control::SetJointImpedance>(node_handle, "set_joint_impedance",
            [&robot](auto&& req, auto&& res) { return franka_control::setJointImpedance(robot, req, res); });
```

I have now moved the first line above, `franka::Robot robot{robot_ip};`, to the header file of this class instead because I want to be able to reference `robot` also from other functions of this class. However, now I get the error:

```
error: capture of non-variable ‘CLass::robot’ 
             [&robot](auto&& req) { return sometype(robot, req, res); });
               ^~~~~
```

Answer (score 3):

You can only capture **local** variables into a lambda function, because otherwise these variables will not be available to this function - you can consider this function to be a stand-alone function with extra data.

But after your change `robot` became a **global** variable, it is available inside the lambda function just like it's available to any other function - you don't need to capture it to use it (and it's not just that you don't need to - you're not allowed).

Comment: This means I should write [](auto&& req, auto&& res) ... or [this](auto&& req, auto&& res) { return franka_control::setJointImpedance(robot, req, res); }); ?

Comment: I noticed a new problem for which I actually have to use         std::unique_ptr<franka::Robot> robot; in the header, and     robot = std::make_unique<franka::Robot>(robot_ip);
 in the cpp, but no idea how I should change the other two lines below services...

Comment: I don't understand the new question... If there is `std::unique_ptr<franka::Robot> robot` in the header, then you can just use it in the lambda, you don't need to capture it.